# Is there a way to style local and global links differently without JS?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

For example, I'd like to style link to my article on the website as [My Article] and then global links like [[Wikipedia page]], [[Youtube channel]], is there a way to differentiate these links in css to create different styles for each type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

Assuming you have a domain you can select **just** those with an *attribute* selector like

```
a[href="https://address"] {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Taking this further you can use pseud-elements to wrap your link text in whatever you wish

```
a[href="https://address"]:before {
  content:"[";
}

   a[href="https://address"]:after {
      content:"]";
    }
```

You can use the same techniques to define the wrapping on all links with "[[" and "]]".

```css
a[href="https://stackoverflow.com"]:before {
  content: "[";
}

a[href="https://stackoverflow.com"]:after {
  content: "]";
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content: "[[";
}

a:after {
  content: "]]";
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>

<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select styling depending on an attribute and how it starts. So to select an href where the value is 'global' i.e. starts with http you can use:

```
a[href^=http] {
  color: magenta;
}
```

So you could set all links to say lime then override that setting for global links:

```css
a {
  color: lime;
}

a[href^=http] {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
<a href="test1.html">Test1</a>
```